# Remove erroneous elements in sequential list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Below is a **simplfied** issue that I have.

Lets say I have a list of elements as follows:

```
my_list = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3]
```

I want it to be sequential from `my_list[0]` to `my_list[-1]`, so smallest value first, largest is last.
If any element does not follow the sequence, I want to remove it.

So for the above example the output I want is:

my_list = `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

How can I do this? I know I could just enumerate and check if previous idx is <= the current, but if you have more than 1 outlier then this theory falls apart.

E.g.

```
new_list = []
for idx, el in enumerate(my_list):
   if idx>0:
     if my_list[idx-1] <=el:
        new_list.append(el)  # only these values count
```

output of `new_list` is:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

So still getting that outlier (0) at index 5

**Note** - I know I could sort() the list, but I want to actively remove the outliers, not sort.

Comment: Instead of comparing `my_list[idx]` with `my_list[idx - 1]`, compare it with `new_list[-1]`.

Comment: Also, what is `m`?

Comment: try using sort() function

Comment: can this list be non-continious?

Comment: what output do you expect if your list is [100, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want every element in `new_list` to be greater-than-or-equal-to its previous element, you should compare it with the last element appended to `new_list`.

Besides, `new_list` should start with an element, not starting empty, or `new_list[-1]` will fail.

```
new_list = [my_list[0]]
for el in my_list:
    if el >= new_list[-1]:
        new_list.append(el)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by comparing each number with the cumulative maximum at its position.  The cumulative maximum can be computed using the accumulate() function from itertools.  Combining the numbers with their respective cumulative maximum can be achieved using the zip() function:

```
from itertools import accumulate

my_list = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3]
my_list = [a for a,m in zip(my_list,accumulate(my_list,max)) if a==m]

print(my_list)
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```